# Xcode: cstdlib and cstdio no member named “xxx” in the global namespace

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I am working on React Native project when I installed npm through Visual studio code then in Xcode I am getting errors in cstdlib and cstdio files. 
Errors are like:

```
No member named 'FILE' in the global namespace
No member named 'fpos_t' in the global namespace
No member named 'size_t' in the global namespace
```

I am new to react native and unable to understand this errors.

Comment: Same error here, I just upgraded from RN 0.63 => 0.64 and expo 0.36 => 0.43.
And now I have this error when I am trying to compile with Xcode. I am using the library tflite.